# Any way to use method parameter when DEBUG=true, like ConditionalAttribute but for parameter

Tags: c#, debugging, system.diagnostics

Any way to use method parameter when DEBUG=true, like ConditionalAttribute but for parameter:

```
    static void Recursion(int depth)
    {
        //.. some code here
        // .. Recursion(depth); ..
    }
```

For my case I need something like:

```
Recursion([ConditionalParameter("DEBUG")] int depth)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
static void Recursion(
#if DEBUG
    int depth
#endif
)
    {
        //.. some code here
        // .. Recursion(depth); ..
    }
```

But I wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `Debugger.IsAttached` in combination with an `if` statement:

```
    public void Recursion(int depth) {
    if (Debugger.IsAttached) {
        //do something with depth
    }else {
        //do something without depth
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help, but Neil answer is more reliable.

Comment: @hanzzbrr it's on you to choose one! good luck with whatever you are doing! by the way you should mark it as the answer if it helped you out